# I wamt write a sybase script in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a sybase query and i want to complete this purpose in Oracle.

Query - IF EXISTS( select Clm1 from T1 where clm1 ='P0C7') 
begin
        select 1/0 
end
COMMIT

Comment: More "context" is required. Perhaps you could spend a little more time explaining your needs? Remember we have no background to your problem - so don't assume we will just "understand" (*for example "select 1/0" looks like it will produce a divide by zero error to me*).

Comment: Yes we need to raise an error while value exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is PL/SQL rather than SQL - there's a difference in Oracle. PL/SQL allows blocks of code, which is what you have.

```
DECLARE
    c integer;

BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    INTO c
    FROM
        T1
    WHERE
        clm1 = 'P0C7';

    IF c > 0 THEN
    BEGIN
        -- Do something

    END ;
END ;
```